# Use of <<++ and >>++ operators in C++

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I have encountered `<<++` and `>>++` operators many time in`C++, but I don't understand what they are. What is the specific meaning and use of these operators, and how are they different from right shift and left shift operator?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just `>>` and `++` operators squished together. There's a famous question where someone wrote a dumb loop condition that resembles that.

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-C even though it's different operators, and C.

Comment: Also, your title doesn't match the body. The ones in the body make sense. I don't think the ones in the title could be possible though. Sticky shift key?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code snippet involving `<<++` and `>>++`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ compilers ignore whitespace unless in certain situations such as string literals.

`<<++` and `>>++` is really just a bit-shift operatior `<<` or `>>`, followed by an increment operator `++`.

Consider this code:

- `a <<++ b` is equivalent to
- `a<<++b` because the spaces are ignored in this context, and then equivalent to
- `a << ++b` (`a` left shifted by a pre-incremented `b`)
- `a << (++b)` due to operator precedence. Bit shift operators have lower precedence than incrementation.

Comment: That's a weird way to describe it. `a <<++ b` is equivalent to `a<<++b`, but it's not because spaces are ignored. It's more that the tokenizer parses it as `a, <<, ++, b` since it ignores whitespace (it's not that you remove the spaces, it's that the spaces are ignored), which is bound like `a << ( ++ b)` due to operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

There are two **separate** operators in both cases: left shift (`<<`), right shift (`>>`) and increment operator (`++`).

You can rewrite the following:

```
a >>++ b
```

as:

```
a >> (++b)
```